# Accessing MovieClip as button with over,click states in AS2

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I need to know the equivalent code of below coding in AS2, I have a movieclip and i want to access a function on click of that movieclip to do certain task.

*The following code is in AS3:*

```
btn_name.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fun1);

function fun1(MouseEvent)
{
    doSomething();
    trace("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was giving in AS2:

```
btn_name.onPress = function():Void
{
    trace("AS2");
}
```

If you want to use your function fun1():

```
function fun1():Void
{
    trace("I'm fun1");
}

btn_name.onPress = function():Void
{
    fun1();
}
```

Or, more simple if you want to invoque this only function onPress:

```
btn_name.onPress = fun1;
```

Comment: Can I use some name for this function? like function fun1():Void